# How to include jquery in mean.io app

Tags: jquery, mean-stack

I have the link

"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
 in the index.html of mean.io app

How and where to include this url in mean.io app.

Comment: Can you show us your files? insert some code so that we understand your set up better.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script tag in the head of your index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```